# How to run pytorch on gitlab-runner via docker?

Tags: dockerfile, cicd, gitlab-ci-runner

I am learning gitlab ci/cd with a AI/Deep learning application in mind. But I wasn't sure how pytorch could be used in a gitlab-runner.

According to [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html):
The following multi-platform Docker images are available:

```
gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest based on Ubuntu.
```

But my applications are based on the [pytorch official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch/). I searched "gitlab pytorch docker runner", but didn't find much.

My question is:

*How can I incorporate pytorch into the gitlab-runner (and gitlab ci/cd workflow in general)?*

*Do I need to build pytorch from scatch based on a gitlab-runner image?*